# swap array elements using destructuring assignment,it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays, swap

i have a array a, and i want swap the value of `a[i]` and `a[a[i]]` by using destructuring assignment in JavaScript, but it doesn't work.

```
a=[1,0]
[a[0],a[a[0]]]=[a[a[0]],a[0]]
console.log(a)//[1,0]
```

but using `a[1]` instead of `a[a[0]]`,it works,why?

```
a=[1,0]
[a[0],a[1]]=[a[1],a[0]]
console.log(a)//[0,1]
```

Comment: because a[a[0]] doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

because js calculate the right side of the equation first,
in the first example,[a[a[0]],a[0]] turns into [0,1];
then js do a[0] = 0 and a[a[0]] = 1,
but after give value 0 to a[0],a[a[0]] turns into a[0],so a[a[0]] = 1 actually is a[0] = 1.